# import module error Python

Tags: python, import, package, enthought, mayavi

I try to import mlab in mayavi with Enthought distribution. It fails with

```
 from enthought.mayavi import mlab
```

and also with

```
 import enthought.mayavi
 from enthought.mayavi import mlab
```

So I had an idea maybe **init**.py in package mayavi (empty) was to be added with

```
 import mlab
```

but now the previous command raise exception with error

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    import enthought.mayavi
 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\enthought\mayavi\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
import mlab
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\enthought\mayavi\mlab.py", line 3, in <module>
    from mayavi.mlab import *
ImportError: No module named mayavi.mlab
```

Some thead I have found mentions that vtk could be root cause for this precise mlab import issue. I had vtk installed with Tcl-Tk Installer. But actually, enthought distribution already include some tvtk package. I added tvtk location to PYTHONPATH.

This is still not working.

Any idea about how to fix import issue of this kind? Or any comment related to use of enthought mlab (may require known work around)?

Thanks and regards

Comment: Pardon my stupid answer below, but I have found the mlab module in enthought.mayavi.tools package, but for some reason, I cannot import it either.

Comment: It is in mayavi AND in mayavi.tools in tree file system from what I see. doesnot fix.

Comment: What does your PYTHONPATH look like?  What are you putting in the `__init__.py` file?  There is no deep black magic in Python's import mechanisms, these sorts of problems are generally caused by messy environments where the PYTHONPATH has been messed up, packages/modules with duplicate names have made their way to the PYTHONPATH, or an `__init__.py` is causing some misdirection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uninstalled Enthought distribution and installed python(x,y) last distribution. This is now working perfectly with

```
from mayavi import mlab
```

Answer (score 3):

I solved this for myself on Ubuntu 12.04 by installing the package mayavi2

```
sudo apt-get install mayavi2
```

Then this import incantation worked:

```
from mayavi.mlab import contour_surf
```

Now I just have to remember how to use it!