# No module named 'enthought' issue

Tags: python, plot, module, 3d

I am having problems with plotting a 3D array called 's'. This issue is due to an error telling me that no module named enthought exists although I have already installed mayavi to python, anaconda and spyder. What should I do

```
from enthought.mayavi import mlab #Imports the module

src = mlab.pipeline.scalar_field(s) #3D module coding part
mlab.pipeline.iso_surface(src, contours=[s.min()+0.1*s.ptp(), ], opacity=0.3)
mlab.pipeline.iso_surface(src, contours=[s.max()-0.1*s.ptp(), ],)

mlab.show() #Shows the 3D plot
```

Cheers

Comment: How are you running the script?  What is the path of the python interpreter that Spyder uses?  Where is ```enthought``` installed?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [import module error Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11804908/import-module-error-python)

Comment: Hi @ewong, sorry for the late response, the path of the python interpretor is in the same directory that Spyder uses but for some reason I cannot install enthought because python is telling me it doesn't exist...